# How to check in jmeter if entered fields remain same in the first page after navigating back from nth page

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to test a page.Where i want to fill up the fields like first name last name etc.and after going two pages further if i come back to the original page by using back navigation ,data entered for first name and last name remains the same.or it is filled up.
In jmeter i want to check the same if data entered for the fields remain same if i navigate back .
How can i achieve this.
I tried gving url directly in the path its not happening since it is not the way.
please help me since i'm new to jmeter.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand 2 things. How JMeter works and how your application works.

JMeter only captures data that is communicated to server. It does not matter how data is entered from UI. It does not check if data retains in the fields or not. It only records the request that is sent by your application to server-side.

So, if you understand above, you also need to understand how your application sends data to server. Does it sends the request as you move from first page to second. Or does it send (Submit) data on final page.

Either way, JMeter is not a tool to test if your form fields are retaining data in them as you navigate between pages. As mentioned earlier it only monitors data requests/responses.

Selenium seems a better option for your test requirement.

Comment: if i want to go back to the previous page is there any way rather giving the  url of previous page. because if i do so it'll be considered as new request. any possibilities to consider cache or any other way possible.(By using response data i can compare old page and page after navigating)

Comment: I hope you understood how JMeter works. If you do then you should know that JMeter has nothing to do with data on page UI or fields. Why you want to test it using JMeter (load testing tool) while it is a functional scenario (involving client side). As i said before Selenium Webdriver is the right tool to test this functional scenario.

Comment: Im understanding what you're saying.I have a user story where i have to check even after navigating back if the page contains the data i previously entered or not.Since im allowed to work on Jmeter only im trying to find the possibilities if there.

Comment: This is a functional test scenario involving Front end. You should use selenium webdriver or any other functional test automation tool that supports browser automation. JMeter is not a tool for it.

Answer (score 0):

**Please read the apache documentation carefully:**

> JMeter is not a browser. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever viewed at a time).

First, you have to understand how JMeter works!!! To do the Functional Testing, **Selenium** would be a good choice.

Thanks

Comment: i was expecting any possibilities of usage of response data.and regular expression .I understand how Jmeter works  that is why i  mentioned" I tried giving url directly in the path its not happening since it is not the way". and that was the scenario in my test which i had to do in jmeter.